# Oracle SQL query to do operations with accumulated values

Tags: sql, oracle

From a Service Orders table (SOS), I want to produce a report of open/closed orders rate (%) per month in an accumulated fashion. The SOS table looks like this:

```
SO      OPEN_DATE      CLOSE_DATE
===================================
01    01-JAN-2014      03-FEB-2014
02    10-JAN-2014      15-JAN-2014
03    03-FEB-2014      10-MAR-2014
04    05-FEB-2014      13-MAR-2014
05    20-FEB-2014      04-APR-2014
06    01-MAR-2014      15-MAR-2014
```

The desired output report (ACCUMULATED RATE) should look like this:

```
MONTH       A_OPEN  A_CLOSE  RATE
==================================
JAN-2014    2       1         50%
FEB-2014    5       2         40%
MAR-2014    6       5         83%
APR-2014    6       6        100%
```

To obtain the Accumulated Open Column I can do the following query:

```
select
to_char("OPEN_DATE", 'MON-RRRR') MONTH, 
count(*) OPEN,
sum(count(*)) over (order by to_char("OPEN_DATE", 'MON-RRRR')) "ACCUM_OPEN"
from "SOS"
group by to_char("OPEN_DATE", 'MON-RRRR')
order by to_char("OPEN_DATE", 'MON-RRRR')
```

Producing the following output:

```
MONTH       OPEN    ACCUM_OPEN
==============================
JAN-2014    2       2
FEB-2014    3       5
MAR-2014    1       6
APR-2014    0       6
```

And to obtain the Accumulated Closed Column I can do the following query:

```
select
to_char("CLOSE_DATE", 'MON-RRRR') MONTH, 
count(*) CLOSED,
sum(count(*)) over (order by to_char("CLOSE_DATE", 'MON-RRRR')) "ACCUM_CLOSED"
from "SOS"
group by to_char("CLOSE_DATE", 'MON-RRRR')
order by to_char("CLOSE_DATE", 'MON-RRRR')
```

Producing the following output:

```
MONTH       CLOSED  ACCUM_CLOSED
================================
JAN-2014    1       1
FEB-2014    1       2
MAR-2014    3       5
APR-2014    1       6
```

I'm having troubles to manage the OVER query in two different columns at the same time.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how to generate two row sets that each answer part of your question, you could simply join them:

```
WITH open_by_month AS (
  ...your first query here...
)
, closed_by_month AS (
  ...your second query here...
)
SELECT *
  FROM open_by_month
  FULL OUTER JOIN closed_by_month USING (month)
ORDER BY month
```

The full outer join will produce rows for months that have no opens or no closes.  However, I think that those rows will be missing the cumulative totals.

A more complete solution would be to generate a list of all the months you are interested in; get the counts of new opens and closes for each month; and then do the accumulation.  Hopefully this shows you the idea - I can't take the time to test syntax and edge conditions right now.

```
WITH months AS (
  SELECT add_months( first_open, level - 1 ) month
    FROM (SELECT first_day(min(open_date)) FROM sos) first_open
    CONNECT BY level <= months_between( sysdate, first_open )
)
, opens AS (
  SELECT month, count(*) open_count FROM months LEFT JOIN sos
    ON open_date BETWEEN month AND last_day(month)
    GROUP BY month
)
, closes AS (
  SELECT month, count(*) close_count FROM months LEFT JOIN sos
    ON close_date BETWEEN month AND last_day(month)
    GROUP BY month
)
SELECT month, open_cout, close_count,
   SUM(open_count) OVER (ORDER BY month),
   SUM(close_count) OVER (ORDER BY month)
FROM
  opens JOIN closes USING (month)
```

(I'm assuming these dates have no time component, so using LAST_DAY(month) as an upper bound works.)

Comment: Thanks Dave. Ill check both ideas and Ill try.